# Result relating fundamental groups and covering spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

During my Basic Algebraic Topology class, my professor left an exercise for us to make, but I'm having some trouble getting ahold of it. Here it is:

**Exercise:**  Let $p:\tilde X\to X$ be a covering map of $m$ sheets, with $m$ prime, and $\tilde X$ simply connected. Prove that $\Pi_1(X)\cong\Bbb Z_m$.

There was a previous result that tells us that the fiber $p^{-1}(x)$ has the discrete topology and $\#p^{-1}(x)=\#L$, being $L$ the set of slices of our covering space. Could I use this in order to follow with anything? Or is there another way I can approach this exercise?

I still want to do the exercise by myself, so could anyone lend me some help to carry on without spoiling the whole result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the theorem that tells you the size of the fiber is the order of the fundamental group when the top space is simply connected?

Comment: @Randall I don't think so. Could you please give me a source to further read ths theorem, perhaps with its proof? If it may be of use, related to covering spaces I've seen lifts, actions of groups, if any of those concepts can help simplify the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a base point $b$ in $X$ and one from $p^{-1}(b)$, say $a$. Since $\bar X$ is path connected there exists a path from $a$ to every point in $p^{-1}(b)$. The composition of these paths with $p$ gives non homotopic loops in $X$. Also since $\bar X$ is simply connected every loop in $X$ will be homotopic to one of these. Hence there are exactly $m$ elements in $\pi_{1}(X)$ and hence it is $\Bbb Z_{m}$.

Comment: Does this mean that the result still holds for $\tilde X$ path-connected but not neccesarily 1-connected?

Comment: No. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Alright. Thanks!